Neovim lazy.lua sourcing not working when trying to install Lazy.nvim
I am new to nvim and trying to configure my nvim setup for web development by watching youtube videos but stucking at installing lazyvim
my .config/nvim structure is
❯ tree
.
├── init.lua
└── lua
    └── minhaz
        ├── core
        │   ├── init.lua
        │   ├── keymaps.lua
        │   └── options.lua
        ├── lazy.lua
        └── plugins

4 directories, 5 files

local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require("lazy").setup("minhaz.plugins")


Your issue is seemingly minhaz.plugins which looks like an empty directory.
You instead have to point require('lazy').setup('LUA_FILE') to a lua file which contains the code required to configure nvim and your plugins.
Have a look at how LazyVim does it in it's starter repo (or use it).
